# How to nicely add a text to a string without plus sing, with shortcut?

Tags: javascript

I have a bit silly quesion.
But i was wondering how to nicely and simply add text without having to constently using plus sign in string ?

```
date.getFullYear()+'/'+(date.getMonth()+1)+'/'+date.getDate()
```

Because if i use something like this, than i will have to write 4 times plus sign.
Is there any shortcuts in JS for that.
I tried to find something like this.
`{date.getFullYear(),date.getMonth()+1,date.getDate() '+'}`

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if it's better but at least there is no plus sign:

```
`${date.getFullYear()}/${date.getMonth()+1}/${date.getDate()}`
```

Comment: To add on the answer. These string are called [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) and can be used with backticks `` instead of regular quotation marks.